# Do not allow another draggable div to enter if one is already inside

Tags: javascript

I have got two draggable `div`s here to be dragged in another `div` but if one draggable `div` is already inside the drag destination. It should not allow another `div` to enter

```js
function start(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.effecAllowed = 'move'; // Defines the effect of moving (it is the default)
  e.dataTransfer.setData("Text", e.target.id); // Pick up the item to be moved
  e.target.style.opacity = '0.4';
}

/**
* 
Function that is executed is finished dragging the element.
**/
function end(e) {
  e.target.style.opacity = ''; // Restores the opacity of the element
  e.dataTransfer.clearData("Data");
}

/**
* 
Function that is executed when a dragging element enters the element from which it is called.
**/
function enter(e) {
  return true;
}

/**
* 
Function that is executed when a dragging element is on the element from which it is called.
* Returns false if the object can be dropped in that element and true otherwise.
**/
function over(e) {
  if ((e.target.className == "boxes") || (e.target.className == "boxes2"))
    return false;
  else
    return true;
}

/**
* 
Function that is executed when a draggable element is dropped on the element from which it is called.
**/
function drop(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the default action of the dropped element from being executed.
  var elementoArrastrado = e.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(elementoArrastrado)); // Place the dropped element on the element from which this function was called

}
```

```html
<div id="join1" draggable="true" ondragstart="start(event)" ondragend="end(event)"> JOIN </div>
<div id="join2" draggable="true" ondragstart="start(event)" ondragend="end(event)"> JOIN2 </div>
<div style="" class="boxes2" id="1" ondragenter="return enter(event)" ondragover="return over(event)" ondrop="return drop(event)">DRAG HERE</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify your `drop` function like so

```
function drop(e){
    if (!e.target.hasAttribute('data-drop-done')) {
      e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the default action of the dropped element from being executed.
      var elementoArrastrado = e.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
      e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(elementoArrastrado)); // Place the dropped element on the element from which this function was called
      // indicates that a div was dropped into the drop zone
      e.target.setAttribute('data-drop-done', ' ');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the dropable div's children presence, while dropping. In below solution, if it is having any child already, then it is skipping from adding the new dragged element as child.

```js
function start(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.effecAllowed = 'move'; // Defines the effect of moving (it is the default)
  e.dataTransfer.setData("Text", e.target.id); // Pick up the item to be moved
  e.target.style.opacity = '0.4';
}

/**
* 
Function that is executed is finished dragging the element.
**/
function end(e) {
  e.target.style.opacity = ''; // Restores the opacity of the element
  e.dataTransfer.clearData("Data");
}

/**
* 
Function that is executed when a dragging element enters the element from which it is called.
**/
function enter(e) {
  return true;
}

/**
* 
Function that is executed when a dragging element is on the element from which it is called.
* Returns false if the object can be dropped in that element and true otherwise.
**/
function over(e) {
  if ((e.target.className == "boxes") || (e.target.className == "boxes2"))
    return false;
  else
    return true;
}

/**
* 
Function that is executed when a draggable element is dropped on the element from which it is called.
**/
function drop(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the default action of the dropped element from being executed.
  if (!e.target.children.length) {
    var elementoArrastrado = e.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(elementoArrastrado)); // Place the dropped element on the element from which this function was called
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="join1" draggable="true" ondragstart="start(event)" ondragend="end(event)"> JOIN </div>
<div id="join2" draggable="true" ondragstart="start(event)" ondragend="end(event)"> JOIN2 </div>
<div style="" class="boxes2" id="1" ondragenter="return enter(event)" ondragover="return over(event)" ondrop="return drop(event)">DRAG HERE</div>
```